# alertDialog not showing when creating cancel button

Tags: java, android, dialog, android-alertdialog

I think I know where exactly is the problem but I don't know if I'm right or not and I don't know how to fix it

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
View view1 = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.dialog_reserv_table, null);
builder.setView(view1);
final AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
Button annulerButton = (Button) view1.findViewById(R.id.annulerReserv);
annulerButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        dialog.cancel();
    }
});
dialog.show();
```

I think creating dialog it should be after all declarations and before show
in this way

```
AlertDialog dialog=builder.create();
dialog.show();
```

but in this way I can't call `dialog.cancel();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a custom Dialog without AlertDialog.Builder:

Edit:

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_reserv_table);
Button annulerButton=(Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.annulerReserv);
annulerButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        dialog.cancel();
    }
});
dialog.show();
```

Source: http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-custom-dialog-example/

Comment: not working in this way i can't call dialog cause it's not declared

Comment: in this way it fixed a problem but the button is not working

Comment: im sorry its working i just didn't remark that i should findViewById using dialog.find ... 
thnx bro